# File disappears from changes list when I do a git add during a git merge

Tags: git, merge

Using git, I am merging branch `develop` into branch `my-feature-branch`. There is a binary file that both branches changed, so it appears as a merge conflict.

```
On branch my-feature-branch
You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")
  (use "git merge --abort" to abort the merge)
Changes to be committed:

        modified: my-file.txt

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

        both modified:   mybinary.gde
```

So then I went into the file, and fixed the merge conflicts. Here's where my question comes in. When I did a `git add .` followed by a `git status` my binary file did not appear under the changes to be committed list, as I expected. Now when I do a `git status` it looks like this:

```
On branch my-feature-branch
You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")
  (use "git merge --abort" to abort the merge)
Changes to be committed:

        modified: my-file.txt
```

What does this mean, that when I `git added` a conflicted file whose conflicts I fixed, that it did not appear in the 'changes to be committed' list as I expected?

Comment: This happens when resolving the conflict means bringing the file back to the exact state it was in in the branch you're merging into. In this case, there are no changes to commit, it's just going to leave it untouched despite the merge, which I assume is what you effectively told it to do while resolving the conflict.

Answer (score 2):

You ran `git add .`, which means *add all files at this level of my working tree and below*.  It's roughly equivalent to `git add *` on non-Windows systems, and almost exactly equivalent to `git add *` in CMD.EXE on Windows.<sup>1</sup>

This had the effect of doing:

```
git add my-file.txt mybinary.gde
```

The first had no effect (as we'll go over in the greater-detail section below); the second had the effect of telling Git to use the version of `mybinary.gde` that was left in your working tree.

To really understand the output of `git status`, though, we need to get into some rather tricky details.  You really should know these when using Git, though many people seem to get by with Git without ever quite learning this.

---

<sup>1</sup>The reason for the difference here is that in Unix-style shells including bash (whether on Linux or Windows or macOS or whatever) or zsh, etc., it is the *shell* that expands the asterisk `*`.  If the command line interpreter *doesn't* (or for some reason fails to) expand the `*`, as is the case for CMD.EXE, then—and *only* then—Git itself sees the `*` and Git gets to do its own expansion.

We'll revisit this in another footnote later.

---

#### The first part of the details, or, Git's *index* / *staging-area*

You may already know that Git stores, in each commit, a full snapshot of every file.  This snapshot is entirely read-only: once made, no part of it can ever be changed.  In order to keep the repository from getting very fat very quickly, these snapshots are *shared* across multiple commits: each file is stored in a compressed and *de-duplicated* form.  If earlier and later commits store the same data in some file(s), that data is literally shared: only one actual copy goes into the repository.  Since no part of any commit can ever change, it's safe to share this data.

This does, however, present a problem with *using* the files that are stored away inside commits.  Only Git can read these files, and literally nothing can write to them.  Git's solution to this problem is that when you *check out* some commit, Git extracts the archived files into a working area.  Git calls this working area your *working tree*.  Hence, the files you see and work on/with are not actually *in* Git at all.

Once you've changed some of these files, though, you will want to make a new commit.  The new commit needs to contain a new snapshot.  The interesting thing here is the *source* of this snapshot.  The obvious source for the new snapshot is your working tree, which contains all the files you have been working on/with.  But these files are not in the Git *format:* these are just ordinary everyday files, not compressed and de-duplicated.

Hence, what Git does is to keep an extra "copy" of all the files from the commit you start with.  These files exist in what Git calls, variously, the *index*, or the *staging area*, or—rarely these days—the *cache*.  The word "copy" goes in quotes here because, being de-duplicated, these files literally take no space: they're already in the commit, so these "copies" are just references to the existing files.

When you change some working tree copy, the index copy (or "copy") is not affected.  Git's index therefore gradually becomes out of sync with your working tree ... until you run `git add`, which tells Git: *take the working tree copy of some file and use that to replace the index copy.*  Git will, at that time, compress the working tree copy, check to see if it's already in some existing commit, and either re-use that compressed copy, or become ready to store a new unique compressed copy, of the file.  Git's index / staging-area records the new or re-used version of that file as appropriate.

Hence the staging area contains, at almost all times, your *proposed next commit*.  Until you run `git add`, you have not yet proposed any *update* in the next commit.  If you run `git commit` and the index completely matches the *current* commit, Git usually tells you that there is nothing to commit.<sup>2</sup>  Once the index—the proposed next commit—differs from the *current* commit, though, `git status` will tell you about *changes staged for commit*.  Specifically, for each file that, in the index, *doesn't* match the current commit's copy, that file is *staged for commit*.

---

<sup>2</sup>The main exception here is if you specify `--allow-empty`, which tells Git to make a new commit anyway even though it's the same as the current commit.  There may be some interesting corner cases with `--amend` as well; how to count these is not clear.

---

#### The gory details, or, all about Git's index during merging

I used the word *almost* above when I said that Git's index contains the proposed next commit at all times—or rather, almost all times.  There is one time when the index contains *more*, and that occurs during a merge.

Git's merge operations involve *three* commits.  There is your current commit, that Git extracted earlier into Git's index and your working tree.  This is one of the three input commits.  There's some *other* commit you picked for merge.  You ran `git merge otherbranch`, which told Git to convert the name `otherbranch` to a hash ID—try running `git rev-parse` on each branch name, or look at the output of `git branch -v` or `git for-each-ref refs/heads` to see that each branch name corresponds to some big ugly commit hash ID—and that other hash ID is one of the three input commits.  And last—or first, in some sense—there is some *merge base* commit, that Git found on its own.

When we're doing an ordinary merge, these three commits are sometimes obvious.  For instance, suppose we have the following branches and commits:

```
          I--J   <-- our-branch (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- their-branch
```

We've run `git checkout our-branch`, so that we are using commit `J` (the letters here stand in for the real hash IDs, which are big and ugly and random-looking).  Then we ran `git merge their-branch`, so Git found commit `L`, too.  Then Git did its bit of magic, which is to walk backwards from both commits `J` and `L` at the same time and locate their common starting point, which is commit `H`.<sup>3</sup>

The way that Git does its merge work, at this point—and somewhat oversimplified—is that Git now reads *all three commits* into its index.  First, Git effectively *expands* the index to have four slots for each file.  Git takes the files that are in its index now, and in your working tree as well, and marks them as being in "slot #2".  It reads the merge base commit into slot 1, and the other commit into slot 3.

Each index entry now has up to three files in it: the merge base version of the file is in slot 1, our version is in slot 2, and their version is in slot 3.  If they *deleted* the file entirely, slot 3 will be empty: Git will have the merge base version in slot 1, and our version in slot 2.  There are a bunch of complications like this, that we'll ignore: we'll just assume that all three commits have exactly the same files, so that every index entry uses all three slots.

Now Git goes through the index, one group-of-slots (one file) at a time:

- **If nobody changed any copy of the file**, the copies in all three index slots will *match*.  Because Git has de-duplicated the files in advance, Git can detect this very quickly.  In this case, Git says to itself: *Gosh, nobody changed the file at all.  Let's get rid of the three versions and just put **one** version into slot zero.*  This file is *resolved* and is now ready to be committed.
- But **suppose that we changed *our* copy of the file, somewhere between commit `H` and commit `J`, but they didn't touch *their* copy of the file**.  Git will see that slots 1 and 3 (base and theirs) match each other, but don't match our entry.  So Git will just take the slot-2 entry and move that to slot zero.  Git has taken *our* changes and the file is *resolved*.
- Or, **suppose they changed *their* copy and we did not touch ours**.  Then Git will see that slots 1 and 2 (base and ours) match, but slot 3 is different.  So Git will take the slot-3 entry and move that to slot zero, and also *check out that version of the file*.  Git has now taken *their* changes and the file is *resolved*.
- **This leaves the most difficult case: that the three copies are all different.**  Now Git really does have to *merge changes*.  Git will do what it can, writing its best effort at merging into our working tree copy of the file:

  - This might completely resolve everything.  If so, great!  Git will copy the resolved file from the working tree into slot zero, erase slots 1 through 3, and the file is now resolved.
  - Or, it might leave some sort of merge conflict, or—if the file is *binary* for instance—Git might have no idea how to merge the file at all.  In this case, Git leaves *something* in our working tree, and leaves *all three versions of the file in its index*, in slots 1 through 3.

When Git finishes going through all the index slots, the merge is either done—everything got resolved and *all* index entries are in the default slot-zero position—or there was some problem, and some index entries have some nonzero slot numbers.  Meanwhile, there are some files in your working tree: for each problem file, that's either Git's best attempt at merging, or whatever file Git left behind without bothering with an attempt at merging.

**If Git did not finish the merge on its own** (or if you told `git merge` to stop before committing), `git merge` now *stops*.  Your job is to clean up any mess left behind, by fixing the working tree copy of any file that needs fixing, and running `git add`.  **Any file that is in a nonzero slot indicates an unmerged file** and `git status` will say *unmerged*.

Running `git add` tells Git: *boot out the current index copy of the file, and put in one made by compressing and de-duplicating the working tree copy.*  If the file is in the unmerged state—i.e., has nonzero index entries—those entries get booted out too.  The file goes in at slot zero.  Slot zero means that the file is *resolved*.

---

<sup>3</sup>For illustration purposes I've made this task particularly simple here.  In reality, Git uses a graph algorithm to find the [Lowest Common Ancestor(s) of a Directed Acyclic Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor#Extension_to_directed_acyclic_graphs) and there are some complications that can occur.  We're going to ignore them entirely here.

---

#### This is why `git add .` resolved the unmerged file

Your `git add .` had the effect of doing `git add mybinary.gde`.  This told Git: *read the working tree copy of `mybinary.gde`, then boot out the slot 1-3 copies and put in the de-duplicated copy you just built, into slot zero.*  In other words, you told Git that the *correct result of the merge* was to keep the `mybinary.gde` file that Git left in your working tree.  That file was the file that was in your working tree earlier, as a result of `git checkout` or `git switch` earlier, that extracted the commit that was the tip of the branch you checked out.

When `git status` runs, what it does—for the *changes to be committed* section anyway—is to compare what's in the *current commit* to what's in Git's index as the *proposed next commit*.  At this point, the `mybinary.gde` in the index matched the `mybinary.gde` in the current commit.  So `git status` ceased to say anything at all about that file.

Note that `git add .` *also* ran `git add my-file.txt`, but this had no effect because the copy of `my-file.txt` in Git's index already matched the copy in your working tree.  Both of these copies were *different* from the copy in the *current commit*, so `git status` said `staged for commit` both before and after this `git add .`.

Running `git add *` would have had the same effect on these two files.  If you're using a Unix-style shell, though, `git add *` might add some *untracked* file.<sup>4</sup>

Now that you understand how Git uses its index, we can describe an untracked file easily: *An untracked file is one that is not in Git's index right now, but is in your working tree.*  The *right now* part here is important, because what's in Git's index *changes over time*.  When you use `git checkout` or `git switch` to select some commit, Git fills its index from that commit.  If that commit *doesn't* have some particular file in it—for instance, if the commit is old, before the file ever existed—the file *won't* be in Git's index.  If that commit *does* have the file—for instance, if you move back from the historical commit that lacks the file, to a modern commit that has it—then the file will *go back into Git's index*.

---

<sup>4</sup>As I mentioned earlier in footnote 1, we need to think about which entity is expanding `*`.  When a *shell*—a command line interpreter—expands `*`, it does so by looking at the files in your working tree.  When *Git* expands `*`, it does so by looking at the files in a commit or in Git's index.  Since *untracked* files are, by definition, not in Git's index, and hence presumably not in the commit either, the places Git might look won't have the untracked files.  So `git add *` won't add untracked files.  But if the *shell* expands the `*`, the shell does that without looking at Git's commits and/or index, so the *shell* will put the untracked file's name into the list of arguments to `git add`, as if you had typed it in yourself.

---

#### Conclusion

Git's index—which you can call the *staging area* if you prefer, since that's mainly how you use it—is a key component of getting things done in Git.  You should be aware of it, and of how Git uses it as the *proposed next commit* most of the time, and in some expanded fashion during a conflicted merge.  You don't need to memorize all the details here, but you *do* need to know about Git's index.  Attempting to get by without being aware of Git's index leads to inexplicable behaviors, such as, why pre-commit hooks act the way they do (because Git is committing from what's in its *index*, not from what is in your working tree).